# React nodejs AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404',

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I am stuck at this error my form was not sent to  MySQL database
and it said this error I think if I fix this it should work but I do not know how to fix this at first I try to use chatgpt but it error at the same point and I try to change the button to input but it does not work too. can you help me fix this

myform.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function ContactForm() {
  const [fname, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [text, setMessage] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    axios.post('http://localhost:3001/submit-form', { fname, email, text })
      .then(() => {
        alert('Form submitted successfully');
        setName('');
        setEmail('');
        setMessage('');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        alert('An error occurred while submitting the form');
      });
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        Name:
        <input type="text" value={fname} onChange={(event) => setName(event.target.value)} />
      </label>
      <label>
        Email:
        <input type="email" value={email} onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)} />
      </label>
      <label>
        Message:
        <textarea value={text} onChange={(event) => setMessage(event.target.value)} />
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default ContactForm;
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const  cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());


app.use(bodyParser.json());

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '123',
  database: 'formgym'
});

app.post('/submit-form', (req, res) => {
  const { fname, email, text } = req.body;

  const query = 'INSERT INTO form_data (fname, email, text) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
  const values = [fname, email, text];

  connection.query(query, values, (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.sendStatus(500);
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(200);
    }
  });
});

app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on port 3001');
});
```

Comment: Is your server started?

Comment: 404 http error means that the requested url was not found on the server.